# How to loop in a table to generate sheet from each row values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to the world of VBA, but I know we can do that.
From a table containing X (variable) Row and AN (40) Columns (image 1), I want to populate cells in other worksheet (image 2 and 3) according to cells in a single line.

How can I loop throught my table (img1), create worksheet according to the number of line in my table and take cells from that table to populate the new worksheet I have just created?

I really need to do that with a macro since i'll have 350 lines in my real table.

**Zev Spitz replied correctly to my question

I illustrated my project with these images:

[my project in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dui6V.jpg)

Comment: That's only one part of my project, the first part is to add an access table to a worksheet and then use that table to populate the other worksheet as you can see with the image 2 and 3. I'm still in searching mode.

Comment: You should not put the input and output data as images; better to include them as text in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ZevSpitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as a beginning:

```
Function LastWorksheet() As Worksheet
    Set LastWorksheet = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim data() As Variant
    data = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
    For row = 1 To UBound(data)
        Set wks = Worksheets.Add(After:=LastWorksheet)
        wks.Name = "Output " & row
        wks.Cells(1, 1) = "What is the title?"
        wks.Cells(2, 1) = data(row, 1)
        wks.Cells(4, 1) = "What is the description?"
        wks.Cells(5, 1) = data(row, 2)
        wks.Cells(7, 1) = "What is the color?"
        wks.Cells(8, 1) = data(row, 3)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank a lot Zev Spitz! This is a very good begginning indeed.
Now, if I want to name my worksheet according to my title attribut?

Comment: @AlexGeo There's a line of code that sets the worksheet name. Modify that line to use the title from the array.

Comment: Instead of creating worksheet, would it be possible to create workbook ?

Comment: @AlexGeo If `Worksheets.Add` creates a new worksheet, what do you think would create a new workbook?

Comment: @Zed Spitz - this worked pretty well!

Sub Splitbook()
Dim xPath As String
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    xWs.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xls"
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub